# Convert Oracle Date into RFC 3339 Format

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a date field in oracle which returns

> 17-APR-19 12:00:00 AM

I also have a time column (VARCHAR) which returns HHMM in Military

> 1810

I'd like to combine these two fields to create a timestamp that is formatted to RFC 3339 standards. Preferable like this.

> 2019-04-17T18:10:00Z

I can convert a timestamp into the correct time using this:

```
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(
        SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC',
        'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss"Z"'
    )
FROM dual;
```

Is there a way to convert my date and time field into this timestamp format? The time on the date field is incorrect and needs to be replaced by the time field.

Answer (score 2):

You can `TRUNC`ate your date back to midnight and then use `NUMTODSINTERVAL` to add hours and minutes to it to get the correct time component:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table ( your_date_column, your_time_column ) AS
  SELECT DATE '2019-04-17', '1810' FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TRUNC( your_date_column )
         + NUMTODSINTERVAL( SUBSTR( your_time_column, 1, 2 ), 'HOUR' )
         + NUMTODSINTERVAL( SUBSTR( your_time_column, 3, 2 ), 'MINUTE' ),
         'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"'
       ) AS combined_date_time
FROM   your_table
```

**Output**:

> ```
> | COMBINED_DATE_TIME   |
> | :------------------- |
> | 2019-04-17T18:10:00Z |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ae00130bdd21e518df81a0a6e37d2cb9)*

If you want the value as a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` then:

```sql
SELECT CAST(
         TRUNC( your_date_column )
         + NUMTODSINTERVAL( SUBSTR( your_time_column, 1, 2 ), 'HOUR' )
         + NUMTODSINTERVAL( SUBSTR( your_time_column, 3, 2 ), 'MINUTE' )
         AS TIMESTAMP
       ) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS combined_date_time
FROM   your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do a bit of string concatenation

```
to_char( your_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd' ) || 
  'T' ||
  substr( your_time, 1, 2 ) ||
  ':' ||
  substr( your_time, 3, 2 ) ||
  ':00Z'
```

assuming that `your_time` is always 4 characters long (i.e. 2 AM is represented as the string '0200' rather than '200').  This also assumes that the seconds will always be '00'.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by converting your_number into minutes and add it to your date, then cast it to timestamp as following:

```
SELECT CAST(
         your_date + 
         (FLOOR(YOUR_TIME/100)*60 + MOD(YOUR_TIME,100)) / 1440
         AS TIMESTAMP
       ) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS YOUR_TIME_STAMP
FROM   your_table;
```

Cheers!!